# Replace Anonymous Inner Class By Lambda. How does this work?

Tags: soap, lambda, java-8

While sending a SOAP message, i wanted to add some custom headers so i did like below;

```
JAXBElement<ConfigurationResponse> jaxbElementResponse = (JAXBElement<ConfigurationResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                        .marshalSendAndReceive(urlToSend,
                                new ObjectFactory().createConfigurationRequest(request),
                                new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                                        SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
                                        SoapHeaderElement id = soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName(uri, localpart, prefix));
                                        id.setText(text);
                                    }
                                });
```

But "NetBeans" tell me i can use lambda expr. So if i do the change, it is like,

```
JAXBElement<ConfigurationResponse> jaxbElementResponse = (JAXBElement<ConfigurationResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                        .marshalSendAndReceive(urlToSend,
                                new ObjectFactory().createConfigurationRequest(request), (WebServiceMessage message) -> {
                                    SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
                                    SoapHeaderElement id = soapMessage.getSoapHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName(uri, localpart, prefix));
                                    id.setText(text);
                });
```

Are both same? If yes, how this works?

Comment: It's not the same, it's better! In particular it does not capture the `this` object.

Comment: @TagirValeev : Nice! But i don't understand how this works. For Example, How it uses the `doWithMessage()` even without mentioning the  Method name?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lambda expression is syntactical sugar over an anonymous class. A Lambda can be used where ever the type is an functional interface, which is an interface which declares only one abstract method. The Lambda expression provides the implementation of that single method.

For your case the WebServiceMessageCallback is a functional interface.  It has the one abstract method: doWithMessage(...). The Lambda expression you created provides the implementation of that method.